# Постоянно создаётся новая сессия

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

При обновлении страницы , либо переходе на другие , каждый раз -новый _token  сессии. Пробовал чистить кеш - не помогает .

Comment: Этот вопрос решен на англоязыной версии форума: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769727/8913631](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42769727/8913631)

Comment: @AlexeyKhachatryan Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в .env записать строку:

```
    SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

Либо поправьте в конфиге **config/session.php**

```
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

120 - это время жизни в минутах
Так же, вы можете в качестве теста попробовать изменить драйвер сессии, например на database.

Answer (score 0):

какние middleware указаны у Вас в роутерах?

для правильной работы сессий требуется указать группу middleware => web

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

});
```

или только \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class

```
Route::group(['middleware' => [\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class]], function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Локально все работало, а на сервере нет. Проблема была в настройках php.ini на хостинге, там по умолчанию был установлен параметр (переменная) "**mbstring.func_overload = 2**". Я его убрал и все заработало. Этот параметр для прежних версий (РНР) который используется многими CMS. А Laravel выдавал ошибку 419 при авторизации и больше ничего, и создавал новую сессию каждый раз при обновлении страницы.